# How set custom fonts for iOS13 context menu actions?

Tags: swift, fonts, contextmenu, ios13, custom-font

I want to customize the action buttons on context menu for iOS 13+

Menus are something like this:

[image]

I thought I could set the custom font like UIAlertController actions like this:

```
let action = UIAction(title: "asdasd") { _ in}
let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: action.title)
attributeString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : font], range: NSMakeRange(0, action.title.count))
action.setValue(attributeString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

But its not work like that, so how is it?

Comment: No. although I wanted to use a custom font...

Comment: So, Apple will not allow any UIMenu/UIAlert customization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't force it to use a specific font and or text size. It actually supports dynamic text. So its size will depend on the user device settings. `Settings > Display & Brightness > Text Size` and `Settings > Accessibility > Larger Text` (iOS 14). So yon can't use a custom font because context menu supports dynamic text. The font used by dynamic text depends on the system therefore San Francisco has been the font used by Apple since iOS 9. For more info about Dynamic Type in iOS you can read this [article](https://medium.com/@rwbutler/dynamic-type-in-ios-with-typographykit-9ed0ac5dbf64).

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 17 it works if you set `_attributedTitle` as the key and using `UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle` as the font size:

```
CGFloat pointSize = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline].pointSize;
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"font name" size:pointSize];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[action title]];
[string addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} range:NSMakeRange(0, [[action title] length])];
[action setValue:string forKey:@"_attributedTitle"];
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to use `setValue` to set undocumented private properties. Such code can crash or fail to function in any future iOS update.